# load a code as the first thing in a webpage?

Tags: javascript

How do I make the followings code load the first thing in my website ? as matter of fact I want the href to load the first thing.

```
<link rel="image_src" href="" id="ShareImageID"/>
<script>
var ShareImageIdVar = location.href.match(/\d+/);
document.getElementById('ShareImageID').href = "http://www.mysite.com/Images/"+ ShareImageIdVar +".jpg";
</script>
```

what I am trying to do is, when some one share this page on facebook I want facebook to load this picture as thumbnail. So i want this herf to be filled out as soon the page loads out.

Comment: the question is not very clear. show us the page HTML and give us more info about your idea.

Comment: @AlaaBadran I added more details.

Answer (score 1):

> what I am trying to do is, when some one share this page on facebook I want facebook to load this picture as thumbnail.

I don't think this request makes sense. *Loading* order will not influence what Facebook offers as a preview icon for a page. Images inserted by JavaScript will likely not be visible to Facebook at all.

If you want to make Facebook choose a specific preview icon, use the [Open Graph Protocol](http://ogp.me/), namely

> `og:image` - An image URL which should represent your object within the graph.

an example from the OGP web site:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />
```

Comment: I tried it but it did not work.
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />
this code will not work because the content url is always will be changing in my case. I do not want to change the url of each page

Comment: @user then you will need to update the URL on server side. You can't use JavaScript in this scenario, Facebook will likely completely ignore it when loading your page

Answer (score 1):

[The Open Graph protocol](http://ogp.me/) and [Facebook Object Debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) have some information.

Answer (score 0):

Does this have to be done in JavaScript?  If you can use PHP, you can get the image ID from the query string and insert the dynamic link element before Facebook parses the document.

This works for me:

```php
<?php
    echo "<link rel=\"image_src\" href=\"" . $_GET['id'] . ".png\"/>";
?>
```

You would use a URL like:

```
http://mysite.com/index.php?id=12345
```

I'm not saying it's impossible in JavaScript, but I tried and Facebook didn't see the inserted image.

You can test using the [Facebook debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug).  Specifically, take a look at *See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL* and you'll see that it doesn't incorporate the JavaScript insertion.